# Setting HTTP response headers with CORS in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, cors, http-headers

Im trying to create a simple website with its backend hosted at google cloud functions. On the frontend a specific user interaction (button) initiates a HTTP request to this backend using fetch. My problem is that when this request is sent, the browser console display these errors:

> Access to fetch at 'backend URL at GCF' from origin 'frontend URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
>
> POST /backend url/ net::ERR_FAILED
>
> Error sending message: TypeError: Failed to fetch

There are two requests being sent, first one is a POST + Preflight request that returns with a CORS error, the second is an OPTIONS request that returns with status 400.

CORS is enabled, and I tried to set the response header in GCF to include access-control-allow-origin with a value of '*'.

This is the backend logic:

```js
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('sendEmail', async (req, res) => {

        //req body validation and desctructuring
        try {
            //logic handling data from request

            // Set CORS headers
           res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
           if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    
             res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
             res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
             res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
             res.status(204).send('');
           } else {
            res.status(200).json({ message: 'Message sent successfully' });
           }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error sending email:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to send email' });
        }
});
```

This is the fetch request in the frontend:

```js
try {
    const response = await fetch(
      "backend URL",
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept":"*/*"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ /*data to send*/ }),
      }
    );

    const data = await response.json();

    if (response.ok) {
      alert(data.message);
    } else {
      alert("Failed to send message. Please try again later.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error sending message:", error);
    alert("Failed to send message. Please try again later.");
  }
```

I think the problem is with the backend logic or maybe the GCF setup, but since Im completely new to GCF, I cant tell what the problem is. Any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried to send the POST request using Postman. It worked, got a 200 status return and I could see the effect I expected. Same goes to the OPTIONS request.When I looked at the response headers in postman, it contained the headers I set in the GCF backend logic.

I tried modifying the HTTP request on the frontend so that it includes credentials:"include", but it made no change.

I tried redeploying my backend in GCF, it made no change.

Ive looked at the logs of my requests in GCF, but there was no useful information there. I could see which request I sent from postman and which ones from the browser.

I made sure I have allowed unauthenticated invocations in GCF.